# Calling synchronized method with two different references of the object of the same class

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a synchronised method and I want to call it using two different instance of the same class. I am not able to understand what exactly will happen here. And if there's a way to force these calls to execute one after another?

`Code`

```
public class A1 {

    public synchronized void m1(){

        try{
            
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A1 o1 = new A1();
        A1 o2 = new A1();
        o1.m1();
        o2.m1();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is only one thread here, so these two calls will execute one after another. You seem to be very confused about `synchronized`.

Comment: Yes I am. Actually I have just started learning this and I am finding my way around it. But thanks for your answer. It clarified many things.

Comment: @Sweeper can you please explain how theres only one thread? Sorry if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: Because you didn't create any new threads in your code. Did you think `synchronized` creates new threads?

Comment: Oh yes right. By using ```synchronized``` we make sure that the thread acquires the lock on the method and only releases it after completion.

Comment: ```acquires the lock on the method```  => ```acquires the lock on this object```.

Answer (score 0):

The `synchronized` keyword synchronizes the access to the method locking onto the object on which the method is called. This means that two thread calling the method on the same object will execute one after the other, while two thread calling that method on two different object will execute concurrently.

If you want to synchronize the calls even in the latter case, you can synchronize on a different object which is accessible to both threads. This is usually done synchronizing on a `Class` object:

```
public class A1 {
    public void m1() {
        synchronized(A1.class) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch(final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Synchronizing on a class is quite problematic because the class isn't an object you own, so perhaps there are other components in the system that do the same thing and then you get unintentional synchronization. If you really want to synchronize on multiple objects, the preferred solution is to pass some kind of shared lock instance.

Comment: You're right, another approach may be creating a `static` object inside the class and use is as a lock. Anyway, I think synchronizing on a class you created poses little risk.